# Apache Storm in non-distributed scenarios

Tags: java, apache-storm, stream-processing

I'm developing an application that processes transactions that contain fragments of serialized messages. It reads, groups and concatenates, and pushs them to subscribed readers after deserializig them.

The different tasks (reading, grouping, deserializing) are implemented as dedicated components that interface each other via `BlockingQueue`.

The application is multi-threaded, but does not have a distributed architecture.

**Question** Is Apache Storm also deployed in non-distributed systems such as this?

Comment: if you want comfortable streaming API with out distributing(and all CAP and deploy problem) on multiple instances.
USe lib that implement reactive manifest like ReactiveX,Reactor,Akka-stream,ScalaZStream, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from running a single-node Storm cluster, but I don't see why you would. Most of Storm's complexity (e.g. scheduling, heartbeating, acking) comes from wanting to be able to distribute work across many physical machines. If you don't need to run more than one machine, I don't think you're gaining anything by using Storm.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for libraries that implement the reactive manifest like Grigoriev Nick suggested, since I just want convenient stream processing -- without using distributed systems.